# 3rd level nesting lookup rewind at level3 in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pipeline, aggregation

I have to add permissions data at each level by getting data(permission object) by permision_id from the permissions collection
at lease one level will contain permission_id and at most 3 levels can have permission_id

Sample Data looks like

```
{
  "name": "label 1",
  "permision_id": "1",
  "level2": [
    {
      "name": "label 2.1",
      "permision_id": "2",
      "level3": [
        {
          "name": "lebel 3.1",
          "permision_id": "8"
        },
        {
          "name": "lebel 3.2",
          "permision_id": "6"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "label 2.2",
      "permision_id": "5"
    }
  ]
}
```

what I have tried

```
[
  {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'permissions', 
      'localField': 'permission_id', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'permissions'
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$permissions', 
      'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$level2', 
      'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'permissions', 
      'let': {
        'level2_permission_id': '$level2.permissions_id'
      }, 
      'pipeline': [
        {
          '$match': {
            '$expr': {
              '$eq': [
                '$_id', '$$level2_permission_id'
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ], 
      'as': 'level2.permissions'
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$level2.permissions', 
      'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$level2.level3', 
      'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'permissions', 
      'let': {
        'level3_permission_id': '$level2.level3.permission_id'
      }, 
      'pipeline': [
        {
          '$match': {
            '$expr': {
              '$eq': [
                '$_id', '$$level3_permission_id'
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ], 
      'as': 'level2.level3.permissions'
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$level2.level3.permissions', 
      'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true
    }
  },{
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$_id', 
      'level2': {
        '$push': '$level2'
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Now the problem is level2 data is pushedd as an array at level1 correctly but I am unable to push level3 data to level2.

Output i got

```
{
  "name": "label 1",
  "permision_id": "1",
  "permissions": {
    "access": true,
    "otherPermission": {...}
  }
  "level2": [
    {
      "name": "label 2.1",
      "permision_id": "2",
      "permissions": {
        "access": true,
        "otherPermission": {...}
      }
      "level3": {
        "permision_id": "8"
        "permissions": {
          "access": true,
          "otherPermission": {...}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "label 2.2",
      "permision_id": "5"
      "permissions": {
        "access": true,
        "otherPermission": {...}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Output Expected at level 2 (level will reamins same)

at level 3 should be array of items with

```
"level2": [
  {
    "name": "label 2.1",
    "permision_id": "2",
    "permissions": {
      "access": true,
      "otherPermission": {...}
    }
    "level3": [
      {
        "name": "lebel 3.1",
        "permision_id": "8"
        "permissions": {
          "access": true,
          "otherPermission": {...}
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "lebel 3.2",
        "permision_id": "6"
        "permissions": {
          "access": true,
          "otherPermission": {...}
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "label 2.2",
    "permision_id": "5"
    "permissions": {
      "access": true,
      "otherPermission": {...}
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: By rewind, do you mean unwind? Could you also give an example of your expected output?

Comment: Rewind means I have to push 3rd-level data as an array of objects but this gives single object at 3rd level.

Comment: Have you tried using [$graphLookup](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) instead of $lookup?